# Is it possible to detect the virus that causes the disease covid-19 with a regular 2500x microscope?

Tags: covid-19, sars-cov-2

What equipment would you need to do to detect SARS-CoV-2 in a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viruses are below the resolution of light microscopy.

[image]

Scanning electron microscope image with colours assigned by software

https://www.sciencealert.com/this-is-what-the-covid-19-virus-looks-like-under-electron-microscopes